# How to get data from join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I have this active record query

```
whitelabel.users.joins(:personal_references).where("
        personal_references.phone = ?", value)
```

This query works but it returns the user data how i can get the personal reference data ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the data"? Are you saying that you want to obtain the collection of `PersonalReference` records?

Comment: Do you want to fetch only few specific columns?

Answer (score 0):

Well I find a solution sorry but I leave here in case someone needs it

```
PersonalReference.joins("INNER JOIN users ON
      personal_references.researchable_id = users.id and
      personal_references.researchable_type = 'User'
      INNER JOIN whitelabels ON whitelabels.id = users.whitelabel_id").
                 where("personal_references.phone = ?", values)
```